# dbt: Model 'bar' depends on model 'foo' which was not found or is disabled

Tags: dbt

I'm using the command line tool called [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/). The whole project is somewhat complicated, so I'll try to describe the basic layout.

Here's my abbreviated file tree;

```
dbt_project.yml
.user.yml
dbt_modules
models/baz/subdir/baz_mytable.sql
models/sources/baz/baz_myinfo.sql
profiles.yml
```

Here are the abbreviated contents of `dbt_project.yml`. The directories of both relevant .sql files are referenced, and dependencies within parallel folder structures are being picked up.

```
name: 'my_proj'
version: '1.0'
source-paths: ["models"]
modules-path: "dbt_modules"
...
models:
  my_proj:
    ...
    baz:
      subdir:
        materialized: table
        schema: baz_final
    sources:
      baz:
        materialized: view
        schema: baz_cleaned
  ...
```

Here are the abbreviated contents of `baz_myinfo.sql`;

```
{{ config(alias='myinfo') }}
SELECT ...
```

Here are the abbreviated contents of `baz_mytable.sql`;

```
WITH sometable AS (
    SELECT ... FROM {{ ref('myinfo') }} ...
```

Given all this, when I run the dbt command, I get the error `Model 'model.my_proj.baz_mytable' depends on model 'myinfo' which was not found or is disabled` None of my models are disabled. Why isn't dbt picking up the dependency?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-aliases#usage), the call to `ref` should use the *filename* of the model, and not the alias of the model in that file. So the contents of `baz_mytable.sql` should look like

```
WITH sometable AS (
    SELECT ... FROM {{ ref('baz_myinfo') }} ...
```

since the file is named `baz_myinfo.sql`.

Comment: I want to re-emphasize that the filename does _not_ include the suffix (.sql)